# Python Tkinter after() Only Executing Once

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Something that seems like it should be so simple is giving me quite an issue.  I have a Tkinter GUI that I am trying to update at regular intervals.  Specifically I am deleting items off a canvas and replacing them.  As an example here though I am just trying to print a statement that proves the after function is working correctly.  When I place a button and click it, things work great, but I would like to do it automatically using the after() function.  I am not having much luck getting it to work though.

```
class app():
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.pad = tk.Canvas(frame)
        self.pad.create_window(10, 10, window=tk.Button(self.pad,command=update)
        self.pack(fill="both")

        #More Stuff

        #Neither one worked
        frame.after(1000,update)
        #self.pad.after(1000,update)

    def update(self):
        print "Updating"
        #More Stuff

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.TK()
    app(root)
    root.mainLoop()
```

Of course this isn't the complete code, but hopefully it makes enough sense to see what I am trying to do.  So when I click the button I see the words "Updating" appear.  But when I use the after funciton, it appears once at the start and never again.  I am also on Python version 2.4.4, don't judge I have no say in it haha.  Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a call to `after` at the end of `update`:

```
def __init__(self, frame):       
    self.frame = frame
    ...
    self.frame.after(1000, self.update)

def update(self): 
    ...
    self.frame.after(1000, self.update)
```

This is the way [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) works. It only queues the callback (e.g. `self.update`) once. Per [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method):

> The callback is only called once for each call to this method. To
>   keep calling the callback, you need to reregister the callback inside
>   itself

Comment: That makes sense!  I knew it was something really simple!  Thanks for the help!