# Background process and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

Looking for help on where to start with this, not too good with Python. What I trying to do is use tkinter for a gui interface but i need to be able to process recieved data and update labels widgets as information changes. I all ready have the communication portion of my program working fine in the shell but when I try to tie it to tkinter it will stop processing as soon as the interface is generated. Anyone have a simple code for me to modify to my needs or point me to a reference example somewhere. Spent days so far trying different options and I still have yet to find something that works.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Convert your working program into functions that you can register as callbacks in the tkinter UI (say buttons, or other widgets), that is, make it event-driven, and then, for background processing register some of the functions with the `after` widget method. The `root.mainloop()` will never return (only on UI close), use it as the last instruction.

So you can't just write your logic in a top-down structure, and hope that it will work well with the UI. The mainloop will be permanently looping, and will call specific funtions in your code, as appropriate to the received events from the user, or to callbacks you registered to run after some time with `after`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581432/python-tkinter-after-only-executing-once) for the `after` part

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application) for structuring tkinter programs. It should have enough info and links for you to study and learn how to do it in a right way.